# How to get Email List with each of its user name?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, mailing-lists

I'm trying to create a report in a form of email list with its user name.
The problem is that each user can change their own user name to be different from the one I gave. The users mostly use Ms. Outlook but may use another email services such as Thunderbird.

Example:

- I create an email for user with email name (account.sales03@barbel.com) and user name (John Doe)
- When John Doe is resigned, his replacement will get his email to continune his work
- His replacement may change the user name with his own name i.e (Jonas Stockhart)

The previous employee that I replaced didn't keep those changes of username. I have full access to the email server and cpanel. So, How do I get the **current user names** for each email name existing in my server? Any solutions or tricks or hacks is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

What's the type of your accounts?

Based on my research, here is a [script](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/1e4d78c7-9944-41ec-804a-61160787c02a/script-to-get-usernames-based-on-email-address?forum=winserverpowershell) to get usernames based on email address, please kindly check if it could also be helpful to you.

Comment: My account type is POP3

Comment: Okay, I think your requirment of this feature may beyond the basic feature of Outlook client, it may be more related to the mailbox server. In order to get more targeted suggestions, it's recommended to post your issue in other related forum(such as any mailbox server or development forums). Hope your issue would be resolved soon.